# Как с помощью модуля commands выполнить команду с sudo в linux?

Tags: python

Вопрос по модулю commands.
Как известно код:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Code for Python 2.7.

import commands

operation = "ls"

result = commands.getoutput
```

(operation)

```
print result
```

выведет список файлов в
текущей директории.
Вопрос: как выполнить операцию если переменной
operation присвоить значение
"sudo ... [какая-то операция]"?
То есть,
по сути, мы должны ввести
пароль, как в терминале. В результате выполнения
операций с "sudo", в консоли
выводится сообщение,
что пароль введен
неправильно три раза. То есть
мне нужно с помощью модуля commands выполнять команды
"sudo". Как быть?

Comment: вы собираетесь хранить пароль plain text ? в этом случае лучше уж делать NOPASSWD в sudo для конкретных команд (на самом деле нельзя на системные команды делать такое sudo, надо писать wrapper, который будет ограничивать действия этих скриптов)

Comment: в убунте есть ещё gksudo,  в других дистрибутивах есть kdesu beesu и подобные. Они удобны тем, что покажут специальное окошко с запросом пароля. Удобно для неконсольных скриптов.

Comment: А может просто скрипт надо запускать от конкретного пользователя и этому самому пользователю добавить права в sudoers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать таким образом пароль не вполне безопасно. Итого, три варианта:

1. Мне нравится вариант спросить заранее:

   ```
   import os
   import sys

   euid = os.geteuid()
   if euid != 0:
       print "Скрипт запущен не от root. Пробуем sudo..."
       args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
       # Пробуем перезапустить этот скрипт (текущий процесс) через sudo.
       os.execlpe('sudo', *args)
   ```

   `sudo -k` в консоли, чтобы повторить (сохраняет состояние на некоторое время).
2. `gksudo`, `kdesu` и подобные.
3. `$ echo "my pass" | sudo -S ls`

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы запустить команду (не прописанную в sudoers), для которой `sudo` может спросить пароль интерактивно, можно использовать `subprocess` модуль:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from getpass import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = 'ls -l'.split()
sudo_password = getpass('Sudo password: ')

p = Popen(['sudo', '--stdin'] + command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          universal_newlines=True)
sudo_prompt = p.communicate(sudo_password + '\n')[1]
print('sudo return code = {}'.format(p.returncode))
print('sudo stderr = ' + sudo_prompt)
```

В данном случае только дочерний процесс выполняется через `sudo`, сам Питоновский скрипт исполняется с обычными правами.

`commands` является устаревшим модулем и он удалён в Питон 3, поэтому он не должен использоваться.

В качестве альтернативы можно указать программу, которая будет читать пароль в `SUDO_ASKPASS` переменной окружения (`-A` опция).

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибаетесь! Команды sudo в модуле commands выполняются через строку

```
echo password | sudo -S команда
```