# Как получить вывод UNIX команды в переменную Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ос

```
import os

def foo():
    sudo_password = '123456'
    command = 'supervisorctl status tasks'

    p = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudo_password, command))
    print(p)

    if str(p).find('RUNNING') == -1:
        print('процесс перезапущен')
```

При запуске скрипта из консоли я вижу выполнение команды `p`:

`tasks                           RUNNING   pid 19099, uptime 0:13:08`

Но когда я пытаюсь получить в самом интерпретаторе значение `p`, то ответ всегда в виде `0`

Помогите пожалуйста, в какой способ я могу выполнить команду и посмотреть ее результат, чтоб они имел первоначальный вид, который мне показывает моя система

`tasks                           RUNNING   pid 19099, uptime 0:13:08`

Т.е чтоб было более ясно - лог консольки:

```
$ python script.py
tasks                           RUNNING   pid 19099, uptime 0:13:08
0
процесс перезапущен
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как с помощью модуля commands выполнить команду с sudo в linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/292305/23044)

Comment: учитывая ваши другие комментарии, стоит явно упомянуть: 1- `'a b c'` и `['a', 'b', 'c']` это разные вещи в Питоне (первое — это строка, второе — список строк) . Нельзя их просто так заменять друг на друга 2- Если вызов содержит `stdout=PIPE`, то это не просто так. Нельзя выбрасывать параметры и надеяться, что будет работать. Если что-то работает не так как вы ожидаете, то полезно минимальный пример создать с тестовым Питон-скриптом в качестве команды для вызова, опубликовать точный код и точную команду. Привести вывод, который получается, и описать явно словами желаемый вывод в вопросе [mcve]

Comment: @jfs огромное спасибо, учту ваши советы и создам новую тему :)