# использую subprocess проблема с получением su

Tags: python, subprocess

собственно вопрос как получить su при выполнении команд через скрипт питона

Comment: хотелось бы  без записывания пароля руками

Comment: Запускать сам скрипт питона через su не вариант? Использовать sudo не вариант?

Comment: а можно пример например

Comment: какое значение вы вкладываете в фразу: *"получить su"* Вы хотите выполнить внешнюю команду от имени другого пользователя (root) из Питон-скрипта? setuid выставлен? Альтернативно, используя sudo возможности, можно прописать внешнюю команду в sudoers (чтобы sudo пароль не спрашивала). Наконец, (*наименее* предпочтительный вариант), [во время выполнения пароль sudo передать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/401057/23044)

Comment: передавать пароль во время выполнения. да было бы более правильно